# Karaf : dynamic bundle restart

Tags: osgi, karaf

I am developing a composite feature for Karaf (i.e. a feature that includes other features as nested elements). I want to write out configuration files for the nested features and then from the outer scope (i.e. the feature that I am writing), I want to restart the bundles included in the nested features.

1. How do I query a feature for all of its bundles at runtime from another bundle.
2. How do I dynamically restart a bundle from another bundle ?

Comment: You can do that but it is not the OSGi way. A better approach would be to let each bundle react to configuration changes. Blueprint as well as declarative services provide features to react on config changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all two operations you need instance of `org.osgi.framework.BundleContext` - you can get one in your bundle activator.

To query features (and their dependent features and their bundles) you need access to Karaf's `org.apache.karaf.features.FeaturesService` OSGi service - for example using `BundleContext`'s `getServiceReference()` method.

To get any bundle (to be able to restart it) you can get one knowing it's ID: `BundleContext.getBundle("ID")`

Comment: Is there a way of configuring bundles independently of each other? i.e. how to pass a variable to a bundle at instantiation time?

Comment: There Configuration Admin service - it should be used for bundle configuration "the OSGi way" - see [here](http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-config-admin.html)